# Given a single die, what is the probability it takes an even number of rolls to get a 4?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

So I've decomposed the probability as meaning we failed $2k-1$ times and succeeded on the $2k^{th}$ roll. I set up a  series for this: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6}\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2k-1}$. The problem is that my calculus is very shaky and I don't know how to simplify this and get a fraction as as if it were k-1 instead of 2k-1. What's my next step here?

Comment: $$\frac 16\cdot \left(\frac 56\right)^{2k-1}=\frac 16\cdot\frac 65\cdot\left(\frac 56\right)^{2k}=\frac 15\cdot\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^k$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: Absolutely, thank you! @PrasunBiswas

Comment: I will emphasize that the summation is a correct approach but not the most convenient approach when it comes to ease of arithmetic.  I encourage you to see the other linked approaches which have far simpler manipulations to arrive at the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6}\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2k-1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{-1}\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{2k}$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac65\cdot\left(\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2\right)^k$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac65\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^k$$
$$=\frac15\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^k$$
$$=\frac15\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^k\right]-1\right)$$
$$=\frac15\left(\frac1{1-\frac{25}{36}}-1\right)$$
$$=\frac15\left(\frac1{\frac{11}{36}}-1\right)$$
$$=\frac15\left(\frac{36}{11}-1\right)$$
$$=\frac15\cdot\frac{25}{11}$$
$$=\frac5{11}$$